# Unzip refuses to accept input through xargs

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs, zip, macos

I am currently struggling with the following problem:

Using a bash shell in macOS I want to search my Downloads directory for a zip file with a fixed and variable part in the name, the fixed part being 'satori-export' and then unzip this file. Being a total *nix newbie here is what I came up with to achieve this using the CLI (apologies on beforehand for any bleeding eyes due to ugly, non-efficient or otherwise awful use of the command line):

```
ls ~/Downloads | grep "satori-export" | sed 's/^/~\/Downloads\//' | xargs unzip
```

or alternatively

```
ls ~/Downloads | grep "satori-export" | sed 's/^/~\/Downloads\//' | xargs -I "archive" unzip "archive"
```

However, running either of these these commands nets me the following output:

`unzip:  cannot find or open ~/Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip, ~/Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip.zip or ~/Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip.ZIP.`

Strangely enough, when I run the unzip command directly with the file itself as direct input (which as you can see is using the exact same path and name as the file name referenced first in the unzip failure message above), using

```
unzip ~/Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip
```

results in unzip proceeding to unarchive the file without complaint or problem. So I'm a bit lost as to why the unzip error is being thrown in my piped command chain?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Very interesting read indeed, especially for an amateur like me who religiously uses `ls` without thought all the time... Thank you very much for this link.

Comment: `ls .... | grep ...` should most often be replaced by proper invocation of `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `xargs` doesn’t expand `~`; the shell does that when you run the command from the command-line, but that doesn’t help with your pipe. So `unzip` looks for a file named exactly `~/Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip`, or one of the variants shown in the error message, and because there is no directory named `~` in the current directory, let alone one containing `Downloads/satori-export-2517846752133086875-68d79887-0c61-43eb-a4ea-750a934a6121.zip`, it fails.

This should work:

```
find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -name "*satori-export*" -exec unzip {} \;
```

This will find all files in `~/Downloads` whose name contains `satori-export`, and run `unzip` on them, one at a time (which is important here because `unzip` only takes the first file name in its arguments as the name of the archive to process; the rest are interpreted as file names to look for in the archive).

Comment: Interesting! Thank you so much for this clear explanation of what was actually the issue and for even providing a much nicer approach towards what I was trying to achieve. Learned something new here! Really, thank you so much for this!

Comment: Or `for zip in ~/Downloads/*satori-export*; do unzip "$zip"; done` (ignores hidden files contrary to  `find`). Or after switching to `zsh`: `for zip (~/Downloads/*satori-export*(N.)) unzip $zip` to limit to  regular files only and avoid the error if there's no matching file (add `D` glob qualifier to include hidden files)